# ListView inside Recycler View Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, video-streaming

I want to make a chat application in which users can ask questions and then videos to the question is below the particular question.
I'm able to display the questions from firebase using a recyclerView but how can I display the list of videos below that particular question? It is possible that no video is their for a question and for some their can be 4 videos as well which should be displayed below the question only and the whole chat continues.
Also I want to know what is the best way to display the video when I have the download URL of the video from firebase

```
{
  "VideoLink" : { 
  "1" :{
    "designation" : "Station Master",
    "download_url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b.appspot.com/o/videoplayback.mp4?alt=media&token=e3be87",
    "duration" : "4:00",
    "time" : "14:45",
    "videoSenderName" : "Garvit Gupta"
  },
  "2" :{
    "designation" : "Businessman",
    "download_url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.cpp.appspot.com/o/videoplayback.mp4?alt=media&token=e3be8cfe-7043-4c0a-80f1-7ff94637cca7",
    "duration" : "4:00",
    "time" : "14:45",
    "videoSenderName" : "Government teacher"
    },
  },

  "question" : "How can I master english",
  "senderName" : "Aditya",
  "status" : 1,
  "timestamp" : "12:30",
  "userId" : "2"
}
```

code:-

```
 reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                question = postSnap.getValue(Question.class);

                if (question.getStatus() == 1) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snap : postSnap.child("VideoLink").getChildren()) {

                        QuestionVideo video = snap.getValue(QuestionVideo.class);

                        if (video != null) {
                            videoArrayList.add(video);
                            Log.d("HELLOOO", "video is not null"+videoArrayList.toString());

                        }
                    }
                    if (!videoArrayList.isEmpty()) {

                        question.setVideoLink(videoArrayList);

                        videoArrayList.clear();
                    }

                    Log.d("HELLOOO", "getting list"+question.getVideoLink());
                    //adding only approved questions to the recycler view
                    list.add(question);
                }

            }
```

I'm setting the list but in get, it's returning null

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I have written the code. It's just that I'm not getting how to show videos below the particular question. I'm not asking you to write the code but atleast tell me a solution.

Comment: Post the code then. How'll we know what you have done

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you now tell me the possible error?

Comment: I'm getting null in the list of link.